# For a global dataset of geographic points (in lat/long) how to find nearest neighbors accounting for the spherical nature of our planet

Tags: r, geospatial

So we've got this working without accounting for the projection issue.  The issue is where (and how) to best add the re-projection so that the function returns the value in km rather than the current degrees:

```
library(raster)
library(purrr)
library(sf)

#example presence data from model
r1 <- raster(nrow=360, ncol=720)
crs(r1) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
values(r1) <- rbinom(ncell(r1), 2, 0.01)

r1_points <- rasterToPoints(r1)
r1_df <- data.frame(r1_points)
r1_presence <- r1_df %>% dplyr::filter(layer==1)

#example survey data
survey_points <- cbind(rnorm(50) * 5 + 10, rnorm(50) + 50)
pt2 <- st_multipoint(cbind(survey_points[,1], survey_points[,2]))

#distance between each modelled presence (pt1) and survey point (pt2)
get_distances <- function(i, pt2, df) {
  pt1 <- st_multipoint(cbind(df[i, 1], df[i, 2]), dim = "XY")
  a <- st_nearest_points(pt1, pt2)
  return(st_length(a))
}

#loop for all modelled presences
output <- map_dbl(1:nrow(r1_presence), get_distances, pt2, r1_presence)
```

Ideally a perfect answer would expand the `get_distances` function to add a new option that does the appropriate re-projection and returns the value in km.

There may be a few different approaches here and I'm curious what people will come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of your question is wrong. You should generally not project your data to compute distances; projections distort so the distance will not be very precise. This is especially true if your data has a large spatial extent.

Approaches to compute the nearest distance may vary, for example depending on how many points you have. But in this example you can just use brute force and compute all distances

```
library(raster)

r1 <- raster(nrow=360, ncol=720)
crs(r1) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
set.seed(1)
values(r1) <- rbinom(ncell(r1), 2, 0.01)
r1_presence <- rasterToPoints(r1, fun=function(x)x==1)
survey_points <- cbind(rnorm(50) * 5 + 10, rnorm(50) + 50)

d <- pointDistance(r1_presence[,1:2], survey_points, lonlat=TRUE)
mind <- apply(d, 1, min)

head(mind)
#[1] 4268674 4261209 4258182 4254560 4220200 4218188
```

With `terra` v 1.2-0 (currently the development version, that you can [install from github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra)) you can do

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.2.0
from <- vect(r1_presence[,1:2], crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
to <- vect(survey_points, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
x <- nearest(from, to)
x
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 5158, 7  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : -2.271833, 22.16701, 48.51506, 51.98087  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# names       : from_id from_x from_y to_id  to_x  to_y  distance
# type        :   <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num>     <num>
# values      :       1 -171.2  89.75    25 8.752 51.98 4.269e+06
#                     2 -128.2  89.75    25 8.752 51.98 4.261e+06
#                     3 -119.8  89.75    25 8.752 51.98 4.258e+06
```

Comment: Thanks! I've now read your functions and this essay https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13658816.2016.1215466 we'll proceed with ellipsoid calculations moving forward.